# WPF how to get site collection from SharePoint?

Tags: site-collection

This is my first post on this forum, so hello everyone.
On Site Settings->Site Collection Administration->Site Hierarchy there is list of sites created on SharePoint. I would like to get this list to by desktop application using web service.
How to get this list from SharePoint? Which method on web service use?

Comment: What version? If 2007, you'll be limited to traditional web services, if 2010, you'll be able to use the Client Object Model.

Answer (score 1):

1. The MSDN does have an answer if you want to code your solution..
   You can ask the SPSite's "AllWebs" Property to get the list of Sitecollections

   ```
     SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
     SPWebCollection collWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs;
   ```

   More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462161.aspx
2. In addition to that you could use STSADM.exe to enumerate sitecollections:
   STSADM -o enumsites -url http://%sharepoint%/
3. Annnd... before i forget that... Webservice would be like this:

   http://%sharepoint%/_vti_bin/Webs.asmx
   -> GetAllSubWebCollection